# add 2 hours in current time in Python and print the time in timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, time

How to get the **current time** and return that in **timestamp** format after adding **2 hours in it** like **1535020200000**

i tried the following but I am not getting the expected result

```
current_time + timedelta(hours=2)

(datetime.now()).split('.')[0] + timedelta(hours=2)
```

since the second one returns a string, addition operation cannot be done

Comment: Is your desired output an UNIX timestamp ?

Comment: yes, it is Epoch Unix Time Stamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all of you, though this worked for me

```
start_at = 2
hours_from_now = int(str(time.time() + start_at * 60 * 60)[0:10]) * 1000
```

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend the following

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
two_hours_from_now = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=2)
print(two_hours_from_now.timestamp())
```

Comment: i tried this before but it didnt solve my purpose as it gives the result as 
2018-08-27 12:45:31.278396 and as i mentioned i wanted the result to be in timestamp

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follow:

```
import datetime


current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

later = current_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)

print(later.timestamp())
```

You get:

```
 1535031690.031316
```

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects):

> Return POSIX timestamp corresponding to the datetime instance. The return value is a float similar to that returned by `time.time()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a timestamp, use `time.time`:

```
current_plus_2_hours = time.time() + 2 * 60 * 60
```

Comment: You are right but the OP has a *current_time* object which appears to be a `datetime` instance.